# Convert colab Ipynb file to pdf with visualizations

Tags: python, pdf

i want to convert my colab IPYNB file to pdf.

I tried "

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf /content/A_B.ipynb
```

" but the visualization were ignored in the pdf. How can I get code, results, and visualization in one pdf?

Comment: some things might not convert.  write in directly in python.

Comment: I want to share my project on LinkedIn, so code text and results with visuals in pdf format